# Google Chrome - how to open to a default zoom level?

Tags: javascript, linux, google-chrome, kiosk

How to open this zoom 90%? (by default its 100% and the layout breaks) or
how to open the browser with geometry set like in Opera.

```
$ google-chrome --kiosk --incognito --disable-translate "http://gui/kiosk/customize6?language=fr&username=S3&password=1234" &
```

Comment: Eh... use CSS `zoom` property? Assuming that you own the site/app...

Comment: NO - CSS do not work in my case, I have a OpenBOX Gnome desktop where windows has no borders, as a result 100% becomes 110% i need to set in the browser zoom level to 90% then it works. How can i do it in the browser (not CSS).

Comment: Chrome extension that will do that automatically, perhaps. There is no default zoom, but chrome should remember the previous one even on the restart.

Comment: Any solution found for chrome apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome loads user-defined stylesheets from the ‘User StyleSheets’ folder.
In Linux, this folder is usually located in ‘~/.config/google-chrome/Default’.
There should be an empty Custom.css file in the ‘User StyleSheets’ folder.
Just add the following lines to the Custom.css file and save.

```
body  
{  
  zoom: 0.9;  
}
```

Styles defined in Custom.css will be applied to all websites visited.

Comment: DARN!!  Support for Custom.css has been removed from Chrome in version 32.